# Group and reduce line numbers in PHP

Tags: php

How to group and remove duplicates from an array

```
$list    = [
    '01 02 03', '01 02 04', '01 02 05', '01 02 06', 
    '01 03 04', '01 03 05', '01 03 06', '01 04 05', 
    '01 04 06', '01 05 06', '02 03 04', '02 03 05',
    '02 03 06', '02 04 05', '02 04 06', '02 05 06',
    '03 04 05', '03 04 06', '03 05 06', '04 05 06'
];

$x = 1;
$y = 2;

for($i=0; $i <= count($list)-3; $i++){
    $first   = $list[$i];
    $second  = $list[$x];
    $third   = $list[$y];
    $_second = explode(" ", $second);
    $_first  = explode(" ", $first);
    $_third  = explode(" ", $third);

    $result[]  = array_unique(array_merge($_first, $_second, $_third));
    sort($result[$i]);
    $x++;
    $y++;
}
```

**The list should have this end result.**

01 02 03 04 06

01 02 03 05 06

01 02 04 05 06

01 03 04 05 06

02 03 04 05 06

Comment: welcome to SO @Leonardo, you can include what you are getting and what you are expecting, this thing help us a lot in solving your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried to solve this for you, here is the working [code](https://tehplayground.com/2S6NXZb2uaSkTAcd)

```
$list = [
    '01 02 03', '01 02 04', '01 02 05', '01 02 06',
    '01 03 04', '01 03 05', '01 03 06', '01 04 05',
    '01 04 06', '01 05 06', '02 03 04', '02 03 05',
    '02 03 06', '02 04 05', '02 04 06', '02 05 06',
    '03 04 05', '03 04 06', '03 05 06', '04 05 06',
];

$arr = array_values(array_unique(explode(' ', implode(' ', $list))));

$min = (int) min($arr);
$max = (int) max($arr);

function findSequence($min, $max, $max_1, $res) {

    for($j = 0; $j < 5; $j++){
        if ($min != $max_1) {
            for ($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++) {
                if ($i == $max_1) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    $res .= "0" . $i . " ";
                }
            }
            $max_1--;
            $res = trim($res)."\r\n";
        }else{
           for ($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++) {
                if ($i == $max_1) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    $res .= "0" . $i . " ";
                }
            }
            $max_1--;
            $res = trim($res)."\r\n"; 
        }
    }
    return $res;
}

$max_1 = $max;
$max_1--;
$result = findSequence($min, $max, $max_1, "\r\n");

print_r($result);
```

Comment: if have a line variation for example 
01 02 03 04 05
...
04 05 06 07 08
I want to make 6 groups and 28 lines for example 
01 02 03 04 05 06
....
03 04 05 06 07 08
How to apply in code

Comment: @LeonardoMachado Sorry I don't understand the question, Please post another question and explain it and share the link of your question in the comment, When I get free I might try to solve it for you. also please try to understand the above `findSequence()` function all the logic you need is in there, else is just to find the min and max values from the data or supporting data

Comment: I'm sorry, I speak very little English, but here I find the best solutions, so my research in your language.
I will post here link with example groups. http://dontpad.com/stack/br/leonardomachado